# Paypal Mass pay fails when large transactions are made

Tags: paypal

I am using the paypal mass pay feature but i am unable to make payments greater than $20. When I attempt to make large transactions (say for $120) i get the error that says the account has insufficient funds.

My account has more than the requisite amount to make the payment. I am trying to find a solution as there is no documentation that says anything about an a limit for each payment in the mass pay api.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: i realize that. I generally am too excited to try out a solution once i find one so i tend to forget about marking the one i like as selected. Im still getting used to the way StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just figured it out. The payment review needs to be disabled or else most of the payment sits in the to be reviewed state and does not really add to the available balance. So disabling the payment review helps. If its already been enabled then accepting each payment moves the transaction amount to the available balance.